# dynamic library loading with linking to static library

Tags: c++, plugins, linker, shared-libraries, static-libraries

I have a program structure that has

> static library(ACE)
>
> static library(common.a)
>
> dynamic library plugin 1(1.so)
>
> plugin 2(2.so) and executable

`plugin1, plugin2 and executable` all use both `common.a` and `libACE.a`
Follow the tutorial here: http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/LibraryArchives-StaticAndDynamic.html.

I only link those two static library when compiling the executable as shown below:

```
g++  -g -DUNIX -DLINUX   -Wall -D__NUMBER_FIELD_ID__ -I/opt/ACE_wrappers -Ilib/ -I. -I./common -I./common/lib -I../inc -I/opt/pct/pctlib/inc -o acs_d acs_d.o  -L../lib  -Wl,--export-dynamic -rdynamic -Wl,--whole-archive /opt/ACE_wrappers/ace/libACE.a  common/libcommon_d.a -Wl,--no-whole-archive -ldl -lrt -lpthread
```

The point is, when I use dlopen to open those two plugins, one succeeds and one fails
The successful one use more ACE functions and the error is complaining undefined symbol as shown below:

```
[CModuleMgr] loadCModule(): Errors occurred when opening the module. nCModuleId[1] pLibHandle[(nil)] sCModulePath[/opt/acs/adapter/libadapter_d.so] sError[/opt/acs/adapter/libadapter_d.so: undefined symbol: _ZN17ACE_Event_Handler10set_handleEi]
```

For the main program, I have tried to use command nm to find the symbol

```
$ nm acs_d | grep _ZN17ACE_Event_Handler10set_handleEi
000000000048f240 t _ZN17ACE_Event_Handler10set_handleEi
```

It is there, but the plugin cannot find it! I have used option like  `-Wl,--export-dynamic -rdynamic -Wl,--whole-archive.` But it still cannot find this symbol. any idea?

Answer (score 0):

> It is there, but the plugin cannot find it!

No, the symbol is *not* there!

Or rather, the symbol has *internal* linkage (`t`), and is not visible or usable outside of the ELF image into which it is linked. Globally visible symbols have external (`T`) linkage.

The most likely cause for the symbol to have `t` linkage is that the symbol has `__attribute__((visibility("hidden")))` at the source level. Documentation [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.1.1/gcc/Function-Attributes.html).

Why ACE developers marked it as such, I don't know.